# Influence Textures

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I am new to Blender 2.8 and how to properly use nodes for materials. I have used the Influence menu for textures in Blender Internal (2.79), but I don't know what these specific nodes would be:

[image]

I have no clue what node could be used for Stencil, as well as a few other tabs. Is this any way possible to access these in node form?

Answer (score 1):

For  stencil effect you can use a simple mix node, driving the mix factor with the alpha value of the image (if it has one) or using the black/white values as in my example. Black in the mix factor input means use the upper image (color 1 socket), white drives to the bottom (color 2 socket).

Use a color invert node if necessary.

[image]